# Ramanujan's Nested Radicals: evaluating $\sqrt{4+\sqrt{16+\sqrt{64+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}$

Tags: nested-radicals

> Find the exact value of 
>   $$\sqrt{4+\sqrt{16+\sqrt{64+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}$$

My approach:

Suppose

$$\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4^2+\sqrt{4^3+\sqrt{\cdots}}}} = p \tag{1}$$

By multiplying each side by $2$, we have
$$2\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4^2+\sqrt{4^3+\sqrt{\cdots}}}} = 2p \tag{2}$$

and this equation is equivalent to
$$\sqrt{4^2 + \sqrt{4^3 + \sqrt{4^4 + \sqrt{\cdots}}}} = 2p \tag{3}$$

Back to our original $p$. By squaring each side, we have
$$4 + \sqrt{4^2 + \sqrt{4^3 + \sqrt{4^4 + \sqrt{\cdots}}}} = p^2 \tag{4}$$

It means, $4 + 2p = p^2$.

> Solving this quadratic equation, I got $p = 1 + \sqrt5$, taking only the positive value. However, if I take account to scientific calculator approach, the answer tends to the surprisingly nice integer, that is $3$. How can it be? Did I do some mistakes?

Adding note:
My friend said that it holds a theorem.

$$\sqrt{x + \sqrt{4x + \sqrt{4^2x + \sqrt{\cdots}}}} = 1 + \sqrt{x} \tag{5}$$

for every positive integer $x$.

Comment: What was the scientific calculator approach?

Comment: Well, it means that I input the calculation by using scientific calculator, stopped until $4^{11}$, and it keeps the answer to be $3$.

Comment: I think the problem is representing floating points with a finite number of digits

Comment: $1+\sqrt5$ isn't all that much bigger than $3$. More terms, and you'll get closer.

Comment: @DonThousand not if you don't have enough digits to perform the calculation

Comment: I get $2p=\sqrt{4^2+\sqrt{4^4+\sqrt{4^7+\cdots}}}$.

Comment: @Andrei I don't see why this is a floating point error. I computed the same value on python to a very large precision, and got a value ~3.

Comment: Is there any guarantee that the expression represents any real number?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The mistake is:
$2\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4^2+\sqrt{4^3+\sqrt{\cdots}}}} \neq \sqrt{4^2 + \sqrt{4^3 + \sqrt{4^4 + \sqrt{\cdots}}}} $

$2\sqrt{4+\sqrt{4^2+\sqrt{4^3+\sqrt{\cdots}}}} = \sqrt{4^2 + \sqrt{4^4 + \sqrt{4^7 + \sqrt{\cdots}}}} $

I think that an a way is:

$$2^n+1=\sqrt{(2^n+1)^2}$$
$$2^n+1=\sqrt{4^n+2\cdot2^n+1}$$
$$2^n+1=\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{(2\cdot2^n+1)^2}}$$

$$2^n+1=\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+4\cdot2^n+1}}$$
$$2^n+1=\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\sqrt{(4\cdot2^n+1)^2}}}$$
$$2^n+1=\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\sqrt{4^{n+2}+8\cdot2^n+1}}}$$
$$2^n+1=\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\sqrt{4^{n+2}+\sqrt{(8\cdot2^n+1)^2}}}}$$
$$2^n+1=\sqrt{4^n+\sqrt{4^{n+1}+\sqrt{4^{n+2}+\sqrt{4^{n+3}+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}$$

If $n=1$, Then
$$2^1+1=\sqrt{4^1+\sqrt{4^2+\sqrt{4^3+\sqrt{4^4+\sqrt{\cdots}}}}}=3$$

Comment: What a such mistake. Then do you have any idea to solve the problem? Thank you in advance.

Comment: @ShaneDizzySukardy Yes, I now write an a proof